# Create an INT index on a VARCHAR column

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, casting, indexing

I have a unique design where I will need to store all data as `VARCHAR`. I can't go into details why. I would like to index some fields as a different data type. Is this possible? If so, will there any gotchas doing this? What is the syntax to do this if its possible.

I will be using both SQL Server and PostgresQL for this project.

Comment: Create a computed column with expression set to `INT(YourField)` and then create an index on it maybe?

Comment: techinically `varchar` can be the serialization form of all other data types and in fact can be converted/deserialized to the desired data type.

Comment: As stated before, you could add computed (persisted) columns and index those columns. But keep in mind that this will add some overhead to your table as well as INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations since the new index needs to be maintained.

Comment: Typically, you would use *one* RDBMS, not two for the same purpose. That's asking for trouble. I guess you have compelling reasons to go this route ...

Answer (score 3):

In **PostgreSQL**, you can create functional indexes (["index on expression"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html)), that occupies less storage than creating redundant columns.

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_intasvarchar_idx ON tbl (cast(intasvarchar AS int));
```

Keep in mind that queries have to match the expression to allow the use of such an index. Like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  intasvarchar::int = 123;
```

(Alternative syntax shorthand for cast works as well as `cast()`.)

Of course, all `varchar` values must be valid to cast to `int` and if that's the case the **superior approach would be to change the type to  `integer` to begin with**. In *any* RDBMS.

Comment: @Lmu92: Right, I left a note. One of the reasons why questions should always target the *actual* RDBMS in use.

Answer (score 1):

**PostgreSQL:**

Create a function based index like so:

```
create index int_index on tbl (cast(cast(num_as_string as decimal) as integer));
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d0f46/1/0

Later, when you run a query such as:

```
select *
from tbl
where cast(cast(num_as_string as decimal) as integer) = 12
```

The index will be used, because the index is on the result of that function applied to the column, rather than the column itself.

**SQL Server:**

In SQL Server you can add a computed column and index that computed column like so:

```
create table tbl (num_as_string varchar(10));

insert into tbl (num_as_string) values ('12.3');

alter table tbl add num_as_string_int as cast(cast(num_as_string as decimal) as integer);

create index int_index on tbl (num_as_string_int);
```

Then query against num_as_string_int to use the index.

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1f378/2/0